# Python : Remove all values from a list in between two values

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list of string values.

```
list1 = ["13:00","13:10","13:20","13:30","13:40"]
range_start = "13:10"
range_end = "13:30"
```

I want to remove all values (including range_start and range_end)that lie in between the ranges.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare strings, not numbers? Also don't use reserved names like `list` for variables.

Comment: You seem to be new here. You are getting a lot of downvotes because you have not shown that you have made any effort to solve the problem yourself. If you post the code that you have tried you will likely get some assistance. Hint: use a list comprehension to filter out those values that fall outside of the required range.

Comment: New to posting .. yeah. Ok thanks, ill give it a shot.

Comment: @Christian ... yeah, i am not using reserved names, that was only to give an idea of what im trying to achieve.

Comment: @mhawke - I have edited my question for further clarity of what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry, misread your question. I thought you only wanted to keep these values. Changed my code accordingly.

```
list1 = ["13:00","13:10","13:20","13:30","13:40"]
range_start = "13:10"
range_end = "13:30"
```

You can use list comprehension with the range condition:

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if not(range_start<=x<=range_end)]
print(list1)
```

You could also use `filter` on your list:

```
list1=list(filter(lambda x:not(range_start<=x<=range_end), list1))
print(list1)
```

Comment: Nope. The integers were only for reference, i have string elements in my list.

Comment: Luckily for you, my solution also works for strings, where the `<`, `==` and `>` also have a meaning.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove the values, not keep them. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Hey, Used ur list comprehension answer which worked perfectly for what i was trying to achieve ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the ends of the list, you can do this:

```
list1 = ["13:00","13:10","13:20","13:30","13:40"]
del list1[1:-1]
print(list1)
```

the result is this:

```
['13:00', '13:40']
```